# Как выставить ширину li в зависимости от контента?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

[Собственно вот](https://codepen.io/Drovosek/pen/jvWqmj) код примера.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при наведение на слово, которое находится внутри `li`, изменялся `span`, который находится внутри того же `li` на одном уровне (в коде) со словом.

Проблема в том, что `li` занимает всю доступную ей ширину и при наведении курсора намного правее слова, эффект тоже работает, а надо чтобы при наведении на само слово.

> P.S. слово в ***li*** находится внутри ***a*** ссылки. Я пробовал вешать ***:hover*** именно на ***a***, а не на ***li***, но тогда эффект вообще не работал.

```css
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #999;
  width: 300px;
}

.marker {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.list>li:hover .marker {
  background-color: white;
}


/* Почему это не работает??????????? */


/* 
    .myLink:hover ~ .marker {
      background-color: pink;
    } 
    */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <span class="marker"></span>
      <a href="" class="myLink">Какая-то очень длинная ссылка</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="marker"></span>
      <a href="" class="myLink">Ссылка</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="marker"></span>
      <a href="" class="myLink">Просто ссылка</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="marker"></span>
      <a href="" class="myLink">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="marker"></span>
      <a href="" class="myLink">Продаю гараж</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="marker"></span>
      <a href="" class="myLink">Лалала какая-то ссылка</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<hr>
```

Comment: .myLink:hover ~ .marker - maker это не следующий елемент после myLink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #999;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.list__link {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.list__link:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.list__link:hover {
  color: pink;
}
.list__link:hover:before {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <a href="" class="list__link">Какая-то очень длинная ссылка</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="list__link">Ссылка</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="list__link">Просто ссылка</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="list__link">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="list__link">Продаю гараж</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="list__link">Лалала какая-то ссылка</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Не, это не то, что нужно. Например li со словом "Ссылка", когда курсор намного правее этого слова, оно всё равно выделяется. Нужно чтобы выделялось именно по наведению на само слово.

Comment: @Егор Спириади - обновил ответ